# Can give some advice on MySQL index with below requirements please?

Tags: mysql, bigdata

I`m thinking about using MySQL to solve below needs. Here let me to give some illustration on my needs first.

I have some network data like below:

```
timestamp
router_ip
interface_id
src_ip
dst_ip
src_port
dst_port
src_mac
dst_mac
vlan
vxlan
protocol
cost
direction
size
```

I have already omit some columns. So I`m trying to create a table with a lot of columns (More than I listed here. May be 20 columns?)

Also the volume of data is very very big. For example the device is generating a billion rows every 5min.

Because the data is too much. I`m thinking split the data into multiple machines also multiple tables (may be one interface a table). And I only plan to keep recent 7 days data.

But still the table could be very big and growing very fast.

When I query the data, I want the result can be returned with few seconds. So I guess I have to created index. But I`m may query against a lot column, So the index must cover a lot columns.

Now the problem is that I have to create a big index(covering a lot column) on a big table which growing also very fast. Is it a good idea?

Or do you have better suggestion than mysql ?

Answer (score 2):

You want to `INSERT` 3 million rows per second?  No way!  At least not on a single machine.  *Maybe* you could do it sharded onto 10 machines.

Indexing, other than with an `AUTO_INCREMENT` or a timestamp will be a disaster.  This is because, once the index is too big to be cached, updating the index will slow down the processing down to disk speed.  Even with SSDs, you can't get anywhere near a million index updates per second.

**The only way to design indexes is to know what the `SELECTs` will be.  --  Let's see them.**

Enough of throwing cold water on your project.  Here's a *possible* way of achieving your goal...

The `SELECTs` are probably statistical or other types of summary info.  So, don't store the data at all.  Instead, summarize the data *as it comes in*.  Take, say, 10K rows, summarize them down to 200 rows, then `INSERT` those rows into Summary Table(s).  Even that will be challenging (at 1M rows/minute).

So...  Let's start with the output (the `SELECTs`) and work backward.

Comment: Not to mention the _petabyte_ of storage you would need to store 7 days' data.

Answer (score 0):

You should hava as little columns in the composite index(es) as possible. This should cover all your main queries. Therefore have a look at the columns you need in the SELECTs.

You could also think about a Master-Slave setup, whereas the master do not use any index (to speed up the inserts) and only the slave will have all the indexes. But this could result in a delay.

Basically I would recommend you to pre aggregate data if possible. The logic which is doing all the INSERTs could pass the data to another logic for that.

You may should use MySQL only to persist the data and handle the queries in memory. E.g. in your prefered programming language or in some Cache like memcached.